# Why we use fixed focus for AR tracking in ARCore?

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

I am using ARCore to track an image. Based on the following reference, the `FOCUSMODE` of the camera should be set to `FIXED` [for better AR tracking performance](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Config.FocusMode).

Since for each frame we can get camera intrinsic parameter of focal length, why we need to use a fixed focus?

Answer (score 1):

With `Fixed Camera Focus` ARCore can better calculate a parallax (no near or distant real-world objects must be out of focus), so your Camera Tracking will be reliable and accurate. At `Tracking Stage`, your gadget should be able to clearly distinguish all textures of surrounding objects and feature points – to build correct 3D scene.

Also, `Scene Understanding` stage requires fixed focus as well (to correctly detect planes, catch lighting intensity and direction, etc). That's what you expect from ARCore, don't you?

`Fixed Focus` also guarantees that your "in-focus" rendered 3D model will be placed in scene beside the real-world objects that are "in-focus" too. However, if we're using Depth API we can defocus real-world and virtual objects.

P.S.

In the future ARCore engineers may change the aforementioned behaviour of camera focus.

Comment: Does the Fixed focus mean the fixed focal length of the pinhole camera model?

Comment: It depends. Please read these 2 articles – https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-focus_lens and https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/3d-viewing-pinhole-camera/how-pinhole-camera-works-part-2